# Python TPCServer rfile.read blocks

Tags: python, httprequest, tcpserver

I am writing a simple `SocketServer.TCPServer` request handler (`StreamRequestHandler`) that will capture the request, along with the headers and the message body. This is for faking out an HTTP server that we can use for testing.

I have no trouble grabbing the request line or the headers.

If I try to grab more from the `rfile` than exists, the code blocks. How can I grab all of the request body without knowing its size? In other words, I don't have a `Content-Size` header.

Here's a snippet of what I have now:

```
def _read_request_line(self):
    server.request_line = self.rfile.readline().rstrip('\r\n')

def _read_headers(self):
    headers = []
    for line in self.rfile:
        line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
        if not line:
            break
        parts = line.split(':', 1)
        header = (parts[0].strip(), parts[0].strip())
        headers.append(header)
    server.request_headers = headers

def _read_content(self):
    server.request_content = self.rfile.read()  # blocks
```

Comment: See the section about [non-blocking sockets](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets).

Comment: WIth HTTP the choices are either use the Content-Length header (if there is a body), or use chunked transfer encoding. A properly written client MUST send this header. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4

Comment: Why don't you use the SimpleHTTPServer module?

Comment: I don't use the SimpleHTTPServer because it takes on too much responsibility. I need to control *extactly* what headers get returned.

Comment: I decided the best thing to do was to look for `content-length` and to default the value to zero if it isn't provided. Like @Keith mentioned,  valid clients should provide this value.

Answer (score 8):

Keith's comment is correct.  Here's what it looks like

```
     length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
     data = self.rfile.read(length)
```

Comment: As he says in the question "In other words, I don't have a Content-Size header."